# Use Kusto C# SDK to load json string and query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to leverage KQL to query data from JSON string that is not from a Kusto cluster.

can i use Kusto C# SDK to load json data and then query it using KQL?

Comment: If the answer helped, please accept it (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). If you still need more info, please add a comment, describing what other info you need. Thanks.

Comment: I will accept your answer just because it’s well explained but my scenario is not solved yet as I want to read local file and use KQL as language to run query\filter on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a Kusto cluster to query data from a JSON string that is located outside of Kusto (that is, not ingested into Kusto), you should put a blob with the JSON string in a location accessible by Kusto (e.g. upload a blob containing this JSON to Azure Storage), and then use Kusto to run a query on this file.

Then, you have two ways to query the blob using KQL (without ingesting the blob):

- Use the [`externaldata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/externaldata-operator) operator (one of its parameters is the blob URI) - this method is most convenient if you have a known list of blob URIs
- Create an [`external_table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/externaltables) (one of its parameters is the URI to the container, where you can have multiple blobs), and then write a query that queries the external table - this method is more convenient if you have a container (or multiple containers) and you want Kusto to look into all the blobs in these containers

As for how to run commands and queries via C# SDK, please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data) doc.

Comment: so i can't use local file? i can only use blob that is accessible to the cluster?

Comment: indeed, a Kusto cluster can only process blobs that are accessible to it.